# getting column not found error for PK columns in hibernate even when column is present in postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have table

```
CREATE TABLE co
(
    co_id integer NOT NULL,
    address_line_1 character varying(255),
    address_line_2 character varying(255) ,
    carrier_billing_num character varying(255) ,
    city character varying(255) ,
    co_logo character varying(255) ,
    co_url character varying(255) ,
    country character varying(255) ,
    upc_prefix character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT co_pkey PRIMARY KEY (co_id)
)
```

I have an entity class for the above table.

The seter for id is

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "sequence", strategy =
TableNameSequenceGenerator.TABLE_NAME_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence")
@Column(name = "CO_ID")
public int getId()
{
    return this.id;
}
```

**When saving data to database. It will throw column "CO_ID" not found.**

Comment: Do you have `sequence`? At least that is what appears as potential problem here...

Comment: I don't know about the non-postgres side of this, but is it because you've put the column name here `@Column(name = "CO_ID")` in uppercase, whereas in postgres it's lowercase? Presumably the program will be quoting the column name in the generated query/statement, so postgres will be looking for an uppercase `"CO_ID"` while the actual column is `"co_id"`?

Comment: It was because of the custom sequence generator extending SequenceIdentityGenerator. solved it by changing from SequenceIdentityGenerator to SequenceStyleGenerator.